# Explaining how a loop can be vectorized

Tags: loops, optimization, dependencies, vectorization

I have an assignment and am given the following loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7030; i++) {
    a[7031 * i + 703] = b[i] * c[i];       // S1
    d[i] = a[7031 * i + 703 * 7030] + e;   // S2
}
```

Firstly, I am asked to determine data dependencies through the use of the GCD Test and Banerjee's Incomplete and Complete tests.

- From the GCD Test I concluded that there are no dependencies in this loop.
- From Banerjee's Incomplete Test I determined that a dependency does exist.
- From Banerjee's Complete Test, I determined that both True and Anit-Dependency exist in the loop.

Is this difference in results between the GCD Test and Banerjee's Test down to the GCD Test being weaker/less accurate? If so, should I always be accepting the results from Banerjee's Complete Test?

Secondly, I am asked to explain how the loop can be vectorized and to describe vector operations implemented by the loop.

Can I simply say that you could separate S1 and S2 into two separate `for` loops, with the loop containing S1 being executed in full before the loop containing S2?

```
for (i = 0; i < 7030; i++) {
    a[7031 * i + 703] = b[i] * c[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < 7030; i++) {
    d[i] = a[7031 * i + 703 * 7030] + e;
}
```

In terms of "describing what vector operations are implemented by the loop", I am lost with what to write here.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is an assignment and you probably want to understand the vectorization process I don't provide the source code which can be compiled ( you should do some coding after my answer). Hopefully, you will be able to solve it by yourself.

```
//The loop counter should be suitable for Vectorization Factor (VF) 
//In this case VF=4 (assume your processor has 128-bit SIMD register and data are 32-bit. 
//1757×4 = 7028 --> you will have 2 values that can not be put in vectos or you must pad the array to fit the vector.

for (i = 0; i < 7028; i+=4) {
    a[7031 * i + 703] = b[i] * c[i];
    a[7031 * (i+1) + 703] = b[i+1] * c[i+1];
    a[7031 * (i+2) + 703] = b[i+2] * c[i+2];
    a[7031 * (i+3) + 703] = b[i+3] * c[i+3];
}
a[7031 * i + 703] = b[i] * c[i];
i++;
a[7031 * i + 703] = b[i] * c[i];

//vec_b = (b[i], b[i+1], b[i+2], b[i+3]); // are adjacent -> thus can be loaded
//vec_c = (c[i], c[i+1], c[i+2], c[i+3]); // are adjacent -> thus can be loaded
//index = 7031*i + 703
//vec_a = (a[index], a[index + 7031], a[index + 7031*2], a[index + 7031*3]; //not adjacent!
```

`vec_b = __mm_loadu_ps(&b[i]);` load a vector from adjacent elements to a vector for `vec_c` you aslo can use load instruction that loads from adjacent elements[intrinsic instruction](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#!=undefined&expand=3537,3537,89,750,3039,3014,2787,2348,515,139,4237,4238,4301,4304,4318,4319,4240,4806,5376,5500,36,864,2226,2242,2487,2741,3015,3031,3057,3767,4270,4922,5439,5676,24,4080,4083,1188,1183,1184,1186,1187,1189,1190,1191,1192,1193,1194,1195,1196,1197,1198,1199,4195,4200,4203,4208,4517,4932,2158,2167,4197,4090,36,103,257,253,256,256,4164,5685,5694,295,5683,3739,2643,667,6,760,3249,1,10,1406,1514,1783,1,2,4,5,10,11,13,14,18,19,20,21,22,23,28,29,31,453,657,670,2025,4536,5714,2447,2467,2547,2591,2631,2603,2377,3164,3156,3147&text=load&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2) like this. But the point is you should store data to non-continues addresses. If the processor supports `AVX-512` you might be able to use `scatter` instructions to store a vector to non continues addresses. 
If you don't have the `scatter` instructions, you probably need to extract the element and put them in different destination addresses. `_mm_extract_epi32` or `_mm_cvtss_f32` and shift, etc.

```
for (i = 0; i < 7030; i++) {
     d[i] = a[7031 * i + 703 * 7030] + e;
}
```

again need to be vectorized and you need to understand the data places:

```
Index = 7031 * i + 703 * 7030
for (i = 0; i < 7028; i+=4) {
     d[i] = a[Index] + e;
     d[i+1] = a[Index + 7031] + e;
     d[i+2] = a[Index + 7031*2] + e;
     d[i+3] = a[Index + 7031*3] + e;
}
//extra computations for i = 7028, 7029;
//vec_a = (a[Index], a[Index + 7031], a[Index + 7031*2], a[Index + 7031*3]) 
//vec_a can be loaded with _mm_set_ps (a3, a2, a1, a0), etc but `gather` instruction is also use full to load from different addresses.
//vec_e = (e, e, e, e) : you can use  _mm_set_ps1, _mm_set1...
```

Finally how to multiply or add? easily using vector operations

```
vec_a = _mm_mul_ps(vec_b, vec_c);
vec_d = _mm_add_ps(vec_a, vec_e);
```

And how to store a vector to continues place?

```
_mm_store_ps(d[i],vec_d); //i=i+4 for the next store I mean your loop counter must be appropriate.
```

Thus, for vectorizing the loop you can use intrinsic functions as an explicit vectorization or you can rely on implicit vectorization such as using gcc/clang at -O3 optimization level or proper flag enabled `gcc -ftree-vectorize -ftree-slp-vectorize`

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the results you obtained for GCD test and partial Baneergy test are wrong. The order that we perform dependency tests are as follws.

1. GCD test
2. Banerjee test
3. Complete Banerjee test

GCD is the basic sanity test for dependency testing. If GCD test proves that no dependency exists you don't go any further. You can say no dependency exists between the statements and hence, the loops can be vectorized. If the GCD test fails (meaning, you see that dependency exists), you go for more detailed analysis. That is Banerjee test.If you unable to determine that dependency does not exist between S1 and S2 with the Banerjee test, then you go for a complete Banerjee test, which is the more detailed and in-depth analysis.

I applied GCD, Banerjee test and complete Banerjee test to your loop and in all circumstances it proved that the dependency exits and loop cannot parallelize/vectorized.

(As you have stated in the question, the complete Banerjee test proves that the have both true dependency and anti-dependency between S1 and S2.